# How to assign weights to counts in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio, unpivot

I have a data set with events and attendees and along with that also the focus area of the events. All events have a focus area 1 and some have multiple focus areas (2&3).

[image: Example Data]

My goal is to have a tree map or pie chart that shows the number of attendees by focus area. If there are multiple areas then I do not want to count the attendees twice but basically assign a weight of 0.5 (when having 2 areas) or 0.33 (when having 3 areas).

Is there a way to accomplish this in Data Studio (can also include some pre-work in Google Sheets)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data has to be rearanged in follwing tables:

Event, Area, Topic, Areavisited, Attendance

Event1, 1, Security, 2, 56

This means you need to unpivot your table. It is possbible to do this in data studio with blend. However, no further field can be added to a blend dataset. Therefore, every calculation should be done in Sheets

Here is an example, how to do this with google sheets using pivot.
First generate a Vistfocus `=CountA(B2:D2)`, counting the focus done at each event. Then do a pivot on that table and add as rows, the event/name and each focus-field. Add a summery row for focus2 and focus3. As Values add the attendance and Visitfocus. In `H3` insert following formual:

```
=If(A3<>"",B3,if(A2<>"",C2,if(A1<>"",D1)))
```

Thus, the values from focus1, focus2 and focus3 are alternating between the rows. Extend this formula over the whole row. And name it `Focus`

Import this Sheet in Data Studio and filter all null values in ´Focus`.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_HxbqW9FGn1FCI8iOOvvz7u4lrs-YsY1V4R7Yg8DBQ/edit?usp=sharing